# Recyclerview selected view null on Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I apply own logic on single select item on recyclerview. when i select item and scroll to last position and select new item and remove background last selected  item then shows error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

**My logic is:**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(SubServicesActivity.this, recyclerViewSubServices ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        String selectedName = serviceLists.get(position).getServiceTitleEnglish();

                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerViewSubServices.findViewHolderForPosition(position);
                        FrameLayout serviceImageBackground = (FrameLayout) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_back_layout);

                        if(!select) {
                            serviceImageBackground.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selection_border_tick_rec));
                            select = true;
                            selectedPosition = position;
                        }else{

                           RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolderselect = recyclerViewSubServices.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedPosition);
                                FrameLayout serviceImageSelect = (FrameLayout) viewHolderselect.itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_back_layout);
                                serviceImageSelect.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_grey_200));
                                serviceImageBackground.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selection_border_tick_rec));
                                selectedPosition = position;                         
                        }
                    }

                    @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                    }
                })
        );
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class SubServicesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubServicesAdapter.ServiceViewHolder>  {


    List<ServiceList> subServiceModels;
    Context context;

    public class ServiceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textViewSubServiceName;
        ImageView imageViewSubServiceIcon;
        FrameLayout imageBacklayout;
        CheckBox selectSubServiceCheckBox;

        public ServiceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewSubServiceName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_service_title_textview);
            this.imageViewSubServiceIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_service_icon_imageview);
            this.imageBacklayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_back_layout);
            this.selectSubServiceCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_sub_service_checkbox);


        }
}

    public SubServicesAdapter(Context _context, List<ServiceList> _subServiceModels) {
        this.subServiceModels = _subServiceModels;
        this.context = _context;

    }

    @Override
    public ServiceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sub_service_card_layout, parent, false);

        ServiceViewHolder myViewHolder = new ServiceViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ServiceViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ServiceList serviceItem = subServiceModels.get(position);

        TextView textViewSubServiceName = holder.textViewSubServiceName;
        ImageView imageViewSubServiceIcon = holder.imageViewSubServiceIcon;
        FrameLayout imageBackground = holder.imageBacklayout;
        final CheckBox checkBox = holder.selectSubServiceCheckBox;

        textViewSubServiceName.setText(subServiceModels.get(position).getServiceTitleEnglish());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(subServiceModels.get(position).getImageURL())
                .resize(150, 150)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageViewSubServiceIcon);
       // imageViewSubServiceIcon.setImageResource(icons[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subServiceModels.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewHolder` is null.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @an_droid_dev I post adapter class check it.

Comment: @Divers, I know viewHolder is null, How it make not null on scroll or any way to keep last selected item position

Comment: @Nabeel just go in debug mode and check why it's null. Anyway we can not help you when there is no all code related to problem.

Comment: When Scroll the list of recyclerview then selected view is hide (mean not shown on screen) then click on another view then crash app on view holder is null.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue I was resolved the following way.
I just created the model class for maintaining the selected values. So when we scrolled "onBindViewHolder" will be called so we just check the selected position and set the background.

**The problem is Recyclerview reuse the viewholder and if it is not laid down the view then it returns the null.**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, int position) {



                File file =new File(imageUrlList.get(position));
                View v=null;
                if(file.length()>0 ){
                    Glide.with(mContext).load(imageUrlList.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);

                    holder.imagePath=imageUrlList.get(position);
                   // Get the Selected Item from model class and set the background.
    **ArrayList<Integer>selectedImages=GalleryHelper.getInstance().getSelectedImagePositions();

                    if(selectedImages!=null && selectedImages.contains(position)){

                        Drawable highlight=mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_border);
                         v=  holder.itemView;

                        v.setBackground(highlight);
                    }else {
                        v=  holder.itemView;
                        v.setBackground(null);
                    }

                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG," This file is Empty : "+imageUrlList.get(position));
                }**





            }
```